# Split a list into X number of columns

Tags: distribution

The problem is to split a list of items into a variable number of columns to maximize the display on the web page ( note, they are displayed from left to right )

If there are 15 items in the list, they go in one column
if there are 20 items on the list, they go in two columns 
if there are 30 items on the list, they go in two columns 
there can be max 8 columns to eliminate horiz. scrolling

again, the goal is to maximize the display which accounts for the slight inconsistency above
to determine the # of columns, i could use a variation of the code 
if ( cnt > 100, col = 8 ) else if ( cnt > 60 col = 5 ).... etc.
but i hope there's a better formula for determing the column count ?

the output would be of the form

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
22  23  24  25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32  33  34  35
36  37  38  39  40  41  42
43  44  45  46  47  48  49
50  51  ........
```

hope the problem is clear, any questions let me know

Comment: Are you asking how to display the columns or merely "a better formula for determining the column count?"

Comment: Does the width of the particular items count? If so, is the font fixed-width or variable? Also, if so, do you want optimal packing so that each column is separated from the next by only one space, or should all columns have the same width?

Comment: 1st sorry for the delay, don't have openID & could not figure out a way to respond

anyhow
#1 - yes the problem is a better formula for determining the column count
#2 - width of items is not relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if count > 15
   cols = count / ITEMS-PER-COL
if cols > 8
   cols = 8
```

does this seem like it ??

Comment: hmm, this looks good
guess i was *too* focused on finding a fancier way !